# How to delete message for everyone after it's been deleted for me

Tags: whatsapp

What if you wanted to delete a message for everyone, but accidentally pressed delete for me.

Comment: this is really a bug and not a feature!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No luck, you can't delete it for everyone now.
Once you delete it for yourself the message disappears and thus you can't delete it again (for everyone).